# 'PhoneInput' cannot be used as a JSX component. React

Tags: react-native

I'm getting this typescript error, but my app still works correctly (this PhoneInput aswell).

'PhoneInput' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type 'typeof PhoneInput' is not a valid JSX element type.
Type 'typeof PhoneInput' is not assignable to type 'new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>'.
Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
Type 'new (props: PhoneInputProps, context: any) => PhoneInput' is not assignable to type 'new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>'.
Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.

is there any way to fix this? I would like to avoid ts-ignore
I am just using the PhoneInput that in my code normally, doing nothing suspicious

```
<PhoneInput
                        ref={phoneInput}
                        defaultCode= //my code
                        onChangeFormattedText= //my code
                        value= //my code
                        withDarkTheme={false}
                        withShadow={false}
                        placeholder={' '}
                        containerStyle={theme.tw.style(`bg-cbg overflow-hidden w-full rounded-lg`)}
                        countryPickerButtonStyle={theme.tw.style(`w-20`)}
                        textContainerStyle={theme.tw.style(`poppins400 justify-start px-0 py-0 bg-cbg`)}
                        textInputStyle={theme.tw.style(`text-ctext1 py-3 rounded-r-full poppins400`)}
                        codeTextStyle={theme.tw.style(`text-ctext1 poppins400`)}
                        textInputProps={{
                            placeholderTextColor: theme.colorScheme === 'dark' ? theme.colors.cwhite : theme.colors.ctext3,
                            onSubmitEditing: () => {},
                        }}
                    />
```

I tryed to contain it into fragments as suggest somewhere but it doesn't work

Comment: need package.json file, type script configuration file